# Load latest Angular2 from cdn

Tags: angular, cdn

I use angular2 with webpack. I have right now installed the angular2 libraries via NPM. I would like to load it via a cdn.  I am unable to find  the latest version(only alphas and beta versions are available rightnow) of angular2 in the cdn.

Could I get the latest released verison of Angular2 somewhere?